# Want to beautify a source code. But gives an exception

Tags: java

I created this code to beautify a source code as the coding convention. But I got an exception  of it. It doesn't give any line of error and my code string last curly brace is dumped. How can I fix it with this code.

```
    String tab = "";
    String code = "class Demo{public static void main(String[] args) {System.out.println(\"ABC\");if(\"A\".equals(\"A\")){return \"A\";}System.out.println(\"ABC\");}}";
    String outtext = code;
    String repfrom = "{";
    String repto = "{\n";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(repfrom, Pattern.LITERAL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(outtext);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (m.find()) {
        tab += "\t";
        m.appendReplacement(sb, repto + tab);

    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    String newtext = sb.toString().replace(";", ";\n" + tab + "\b");
    p = Pattern.compile("}", Pattern.LITERAL);
    m = p.matcher(newtext);

    repto = "}\n";
    sb = new StringBuffer();
    String back = "";
    String tab2 = tab;

    while (m.find()) {
        try {
            tab2 = tab2.substring(0, tab2.length() - 2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        back += "\b";
        m.appendReplacement(sb, tab2 + back + repto + tab + back);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

My exception is...

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contents must be presorted - added value 162 is less than preceding value 163
at org.netbeans.core.output2.IntList.add(IntList.java:76)
at org.netbeans.core.output2.AbstractLines.addTabAt(AbstractLines.java:1131)
at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.doWrite(OutWriter.java:445)
at org.netbeans.core.output2.OutWriter.write(OutWriter.java:499)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.ForkedJavaOverride$Copier.maybeFlush(ForkedJavaOverride.java:350)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.ForkedJavaOverride$Copier.access$000(ForkedJavaOverride.java:251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.ForkedJavaOverride$NbRedirector$NbOutputStreamHandler.stop(ForkedJavaOverride.java:203)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:521)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.fork(Java.java:791)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:214)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.executeJava(Java.java:135)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Java.execute(Java.java:108)
at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor116.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:283)
at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
```

Java Result: -1

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't see any class that might be written by you in that stacktrace. What are you doing that creates it?

Comment: I haven't found the source of the exception yet, but in your code string, you try to return a string from a void function, so that will break if you ever try to compile it. Just a side note.

Comment: My Class name is SyntaxTester. But it is not mentioned in exception.

Comment: on another note why not use one of the many freely available, customisable, formatters (beautifiers) already available? Like the one built into NetBeans?

Comment: @Caleryn - Please give me a link for it.

Comment: Built into any NetBeans install ... to Use Right click on code : Format

Comment: Its Setup via the Tools Menu: options -> Editor Icon -> Formatting Tab. -> Set Language = Java

Comment: Yes I knew it. I'm creating a java question database. I'm copying code from a pdf and it is not according to the convention. When I press a button(such as ctrl+k in stack overflow) I want to create that string according to the convention.

Answer (score 0):

The stacktrace only contains code from netbeans (which is where I assume you are running this). Searching for that exception and 'netbeans' shows there are a number of open bugs regarding this and netbeans -https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201450

I would try a different IDE or compile it on the command-line.

Comment: Yes. It works with other IDE. But output is wrong. When I set this output to a jSyntaxPane. It shows squares some places.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but if you're hitting an error in netbeans, which as far as I can see is un-resolved, can you expect your own code to run?